# How to dynamically add property to JSON response (I don't control the API)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

EDIT (ANSWERD): To mutate the objects all I needed to do was

```
return {
        ...post,
        companyName: companyNameCreate
      }
```

I hope this helps other people who have not mutated a json api object before saving it into a react state!

Q: I have a web scraping service that is **scraping** LinkedIn profile posts from 6 different companies.

I am using the JSON response from this service to render a news feed of all the posts in a react component.

I want to add a company name property to each of the linkedin company post objects as they don't have one already.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-propertys-to-json-response-2x1ym - This is what I am trying to do. I would like to set the company name in the setState function.

Comment: You're just talking about manipulating an object. It doesn't have much to do with React or JSON. What have you tried? What's not working? You need to show code _here_.

Comment: How you know which company belogs to each post? Where will you get the companies names?

Comment: Unsolicited pedantry: "companies" and "properties"

Comment: I know I need to create an if/switch statement to check if the profileUrl property matches either of the 6 unique profileUrls on the json response @ChristosLytras Then create a property company name for each... I am just quite new to oop, my background is mainly web design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `profileUrl` and some RegExp to format the company name from the URL:

```
private getProfilesPosts() {
  axios
    .get(
        "https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json"
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        // TODO: Set a company name property for each linkedin post object
        // TODO: There are 6 different companys
        // TODO: The unique propertys to check which company the post belongs to is by the profileUrl property
        //       i.e  profileUrl: "https://www.linkedin.com/company/..." or profileUrl: "https://www.linkedin.com/company/..."
        posts: response.data.filter(d => d.postContent && d.imgUrl).map(post => {
          return {
            ...post,
            companyName: post.profileUrl
              .match(/\/company\/(.*)/)[1]
              .replace('-', ' ')
              .split(' ')
              .map(v => v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.slice(1))
              .join(' ')
          }
        })
      });
    })
    // Error catching
    .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors }));
}
```

Check the result: https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-propertys-to-json-response-u3h93

Comment: I will accept it as the right answer as I adjusted it to do what I needed. I used an if statement to check the urls then assigned a companyName variable to the correct spelling of each company instead of the regex :)

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly fix this by getting the company url from their response like this:

```
<h1> //TODO: Company Name {post.profileUrl.split('/')[post.profileUrl.split('/').length-1]} </h1>

Expected -> //TODO: Company Name ab...
```

However, I think that you will need to call another one of their API's to get company names based on id's or routes.

Comment: This is not a bad idea, I had thought of this. But wanted to add my own propertys instead.

Comment: Yes, but I think it would be safer to get the actual string of the company name from the LinkedIn's API as the route could be old and the company could have changed their name to something else.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a object/map where unique urls are keys and company names are values e.g.

```js
const mapping = {
   "https://some-url-1": "Company Name 1",
   "https://some-url-2": "Company Name 2",
}


axios
      .get(
        "https://phantombuster.s3.amazonaws.com/YRrbtT9qhg0/3jhBGwtSbaEV6lqijSmpoQ/result.json"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          posts: response.data.filter(d => d.postContent && d.imgUrl)
          .map(item => {
             const name = mappings[item.url];
             return { ...item, name };
          });
        });
      })
```